# How to arrange layouts with many view controls

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want the screen like this :
![my screen schema][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBt0i.png
How should be the layout?
I have given some fixed width and height but this is not good practice please help me in designing this screen.

For more details below is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".QuestionBankActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orangewood"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gray_back"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:text="@string/QuesPalet"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="334dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:weightSum="4"

        android:background="@drawable/orangewood"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reviewBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gray_back"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gray_back"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveNextBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gray_back"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_marginLeft=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"            
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"            
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"            
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/custom_radio"
            android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"         
        android:layout_weight="1"   
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!!
**Note** that I am using scale to width of views but this is bad coding because it will not fit to various screens.Please correct me if I am wrong! feel free to ask any details regarding this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reviewBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveNextBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

its a dummy code check this and create your own :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need relative layout and Linearlayout... and scrollLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"

        android:background="#e66b7a">

   //put here btn and textview

</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4.12"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >


            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="3dp" >

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/webcontain"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>



        </RelativeLayout>
//put here radio button
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/footer"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/footer"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="SET"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/footer"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="SET"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/footer"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="SET"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is code for 4 radio button.. this will fit in all size of screens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbutton"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
           />

</LinearLayout>  
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbuttodn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
         />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbuttdtgyodn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
         />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/okbuttrtodn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:text="SET"
         />
      </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/weblayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Webview"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rdbtndlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weblayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Rd1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Rd2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Rd3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Rd4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rdbtndlayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout >
```

You can place your webview and radiogroups inside respective layouts

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".QuestionBankActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:text="QuesPalet"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```